# django url _reverse _ not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-urls, django-url-reverse

[image]

the redirect url is
"liveinterviewList/2"

and, ofcourse, I declare that url in url.py
more over, when I type that url in browser manualy, it works well.
what's the matter?

more question.
at this case, I write the user_id on the url.
I think, it is not good way to make url pattern.
but I don't know how I deliver the user_id variable without url pattern.

please give me a hint.

Comment: Please copy and paste code instead of using screenshots. It makes it easier to answer your question and search for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django `reverse` function accepts the name of the path not the URL.

lets say i have url patterns like this

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('/users/list', name="users-list")
]
```

In my view i can use like this

```
def my_view(request):
     return redirect(reverse("users-list"));
```

Comment: tough I fix my bug with another answer, your answer is containing more hints. I'll refer to your method next time. thankyou very much

Answer (score 1):

What HariHaraSudhan left out was how to use parameters.  For your case, you would want something like:

```
path(r'liveinterviewList/<int:userId>', ..., name='live-interview'),
```

And then when you are ready to reverse, use this:

```
reverse('app:live-interview', kwargs={ 'userId': userId })
```

where app is the name of the app in which your view lives.  If your url lives in the main urls file , you don't need the `app:` prefix.

Comment: Note that you don't need to use `reverse` with `redirect`. Instead of `return redirect(reverse('app:live-interview', kwargs={ 'userId': userId }))` you can use `return redirect('app:live-interview', userId=userId)`

Comment: I fixed my bug with another opinion, easier way to implement. but your advise is deeper than another answers. so I'll study with your answers. thankyou very much

Answer (score 0):

You should add a name to your path url and use it to redirect.

As the django doc says :

urls :

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('/name', name="some-view-name")
]

def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('some-view-name')
```